# how to return row if value find in array in postgres

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

```
{
    actName: null,
    applicable: {
      applicable: [ 5, 4, 1 ]
  },
   status: 1,
   id: 2
}
{
    actName: null,
    applicable: {
      applicable: [ 3, 2 ]
  },
   status: 1,
   id: 1
}
```

Is that possible to find value in array, like if i search integer value `2` in `applicable` array return one row with id 1.

Comment: You can use the array "contains" operator like this:  `applicable @> array[2]`

Comment: you have invalid json structure

Comment: @Dmitry You should never alter the question code or data. That is part of the question.

Comment: it's surprise for me that json above is valid, you are using slitly different structure in your answer;  but understood to keep questions untouched @ClodoaldoNeto

Comment: @Dmitry Your guess about the structure is a good one and you can highlight it in your nice answer. But it is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
with t(j) as (values
    ('{
        "actName": null,
        "applicable": {
            "applicable": [ 5, 4, 1 ]
        },
        "status": 1,
        "id": 2
    }'::jsonb),
    ('{
        "actName": null,
        "applicable": {
            "applicable": [ 3, 2 ]
        },
        "status": 1,
        "id": 1
    }')
)
select j ->> 'id' as id
from t
where exists (
    select 1
    from jsonb_array_elements_text(j -> 'applicable' -> 'applicable') s(i)
    where i = '2'
)
;
 id 
----
 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption here is that you have `jsonb` with array of json docs in your database**, query may be the following:

```
WITH test_data AS (
    SELECT '[{
      "actName": "null",
      "applicable": {
        "applicable": [5,4,1]
      },
      "status":1,
      "id":2
      },
      {
      "actName": "null",
      "applicable": {
        "applicable": [3,2]
      },
      "status": 1,
      "id": 1
    }]'::JSONB AS jsonb_value
)
SELECT 
  jsonb_doc->>'id' AS id,
  jsonb_doc->'applicable' #>'{applicable}' AS appl_array_result
FROM
  test_data td,
  jsonb_array_elements(td.jsonb_value) AS jsonb_doc
WHERE (jsonb_doc->'applicable' #>'{applicable}') @> '2'::JSONB;
```

Output:

```
 id | appl_array_result 
----+-------------------
 1  | [3, 2]
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

With JSONB's `@>` you can query for any element by following the structure of your document, for example:

```
WITH data(d) AS (VALUES
    ('{
        "actName": null,
        "applicable": {
            "applicable": [ 5, 4, 1 ]
        },
        "status": 1,
        "id": 2
    }'::JSONB),
    ('{
        "actName": null,
        "applicable": {
            "applicable": [ 3, 2 ]
        },
        "status": 1,
        "id": 1
    }')
)
SELECT d ->> 'id' AS id
FROM data
WHERE d @> '{"applicable":{"applicable":[1]}}';
```